# Select distinct values from MongoDB array using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get a list of unique values from a List field called categories.

I am using Java and MongoDB. Most of the examples and docs I can see seem to suggest I need to do something like what I have below:

```
public static List<String> listCategories(String input) {

    Datastore ds = Dao.instance().getDatabase();
    BasicDBObject dbObject=new BasicDBObject("categories", input);
    DBCollection dBCollection = ds.getCollection(Product.class);
    List<String> categories = dBCollection.distinct("categories",dbObject);

    return categories;
}
```

However when I test it using this code:

```
@Test
public void testListCategories(){
    List<String> categories = Product.listCategories("S");
    Assert.assertTrue(categories.size() > 0);
}
```

The test fails even though I know there are categories that start with S (have also tried a few others just to be sure).

Is it even possible to do this, if so do you have any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
BasicDBObject dbObject=new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.append(categories", input);
```

Now it will be like a where condition,

```
DBCollection dBCollection = ds.getCollection(Product.class);
 List<String> categories = dBCollection.distinct("categories",dbObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

> *The test fails even though I know there are categories that start with S (have also tried a few others just to be sure).*

You need to perform a `regex` match using the `$regex` operator on the `categories` field to find `distinct` categories that start with a particular `input`.

Your updated code should look like:

```
BasicDBObject like = new BasicDBObject("$regex",
                         java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^"+input,
                                                      Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("categories", like);
List<String> categories = dBCollection.distinct("categories",query);
```